# How to hide file url in file download in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site in which some files are allowed  to few members only
So after going to restricted area the url is shown as

```
http://domainname/theme_name/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/file_name.pdf
```

I have managed forced download  but still by viewing source anyone can see absolute url
So i  want to hide this url and show something like

```
http://domainname/theme_name/duplicate_name.pdf
```

or some other suggestions. Help me if it is possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to hide this url. If you include the Url on a page, you are making it public. I would be interested to see the answers you get.

Comment: So how can i make file available for download other than using a tag? Like readfile() or something?

Comment: Or should i use one time usable url?